# Issue with Adding Components to React Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

My **core issue** is more related to the following (which is located at the bottom): how/why can't I loop through an array and return React Components. See comment in code that says `I never see this, why can't I reach this`

I'm adding an npm package called `vertical-timeline-component-react` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vertical-timeline-component-react)).

The core structure of using this component is as follows:

```
<Timeline theme={customTheme} dateFormat='ll'>
  <Container>
    <YearContent startDate='2020/07/01' />
    <BodyContent>
      <Section title='Comment'>
        <Description text='Here is a descriptive comment about this Item' />
      </Section>
    </BodyContent>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <YearContent startDate='2020/05/10' />
    <BodyContent>      
      <Section title='Comment'>
        <Description text='Waiting to hear back from user' />
      </Section>
      <Section title='Edit'>
        <Description text='Added new User: Sam Smith' />
      </Section>
    </BodyContent>
  </Container>
</Timeline>
```

I have a SQL Table for a history of all changes throughout my application for an admin page. When I return this data, the core structure looks like this

```
{
"2018/02/15": [{data for section}, {data for section}]}
"2018/02/05": [{data for section}, {data for section}, {data for section}]}
"2017/12/25": [{data for section}]}
```

This way, I can loop through each "Container" of my Timeline using my objects key (which is the startDate), and inside of each "Container" I can loop through each "Section".

I hope all that makes sense. With this knowledge, here is my code:

```
// Imports here

export default function Timeline() {
  // call to server for data which is saved to results.data.history

  const history = results.data.history
  return (
    <Timeline theme={customTheme} dateFormat='ll'>
      {Object.keys(history).forEach(startDate => {
        console.log(startDate) // I can see the start date printed
        return (
          <TimelineContainer startDate={startDate} sections={history[startDate]} />
        )
      })}
    </Timeline>
  )
}

const TimelineContainer = ({startDate, sections}) => {
  console.log("Inside Container") // <--- I never see this, why can't I reach this
  console.log(startDate)
  console.log(sections)
  var timelinesections = sections.map(section => {
    return <TimelineSection
      user={section.user}
      action={section.action}
      parent_type={section.parent_type}
      parent_id={section.parent_id}
      field_type={section.field_type}
      old_value={section.old_value}
      new_value={section.new_value}
    />
  })
  return (
    <Container>
      <YearContent startDate={startDate} />
      <BodyContent>
        {timelinesections}
      </BodyContent>
    </Container>
  )
}

const TimelineSection = ({ key, user, action, parent_type, parent_id, field_type, old_value, new_value }) => {
  return (
    <Section key={key} title={parent_type + ': ' + field_type} >
      <Description variant='subtitle' text={'Subtitle if needed'} />
      <Description text={user + ' ' + action + 'ed: old value was ' + old_value + ' and new value is ' + new_value} />
    </ Section>
  )
}
```

I'm tried using `const ComponentName = () => {}` and `function ComponentName() {}`. Is this not the right way to create React Components? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Hello. Can you tell us what exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Both ways of declaring components should be fine. Did you check for any errors in the console ?

Comment: Emmanuel, check my update.

Comment: Sushanth, no errors in my console. As the comments show, I can see my keys, but I never reach my console.logs for the component `TimelineContainer`. I don't know why I never reach those console.logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` iterates over the entities and does not return anything. It just executes the following statements. You are looking for `.map` here.

Replace `forEach` with `map`

```
{Object.keys(history).map(startDate => {
    console.log(startDate) // I can see the start date printed
        
    return (
      <TimelineContainer key={startDate} startDate={startDate} sections={history[startDate]} />
    )
})}
```

Comment: This is both awkward, and what programming is all about. Simple mistakes that boggle ones mind until someone points out the obvious. Thank you so much @Sushanth, exactly what I need.